# How can I get a program I run in Wine to lock to my launcher?

Tags: unity, wine, launcher, icons, evernote

I installed Evernote with Wine on Ubuntu 14.04, and it works great.  I'd love to have the icon stay on the Launcher for speedy access, but when I right-click and select that option, all I get is the Wine icon that does nothing when I click on it later.  How can I get an Evernote icon?

Comment: Do you have a working desktop icon?  right-click on what and select what option?  Just dragging the desktop icon to the taskbar should install it.

Comment: I don't have a desktop icon.  What I meant is while Evernote is running, there is an icon on the launcher.  And when I close the program, it disappears.  To have it stay on the launcher (for one-click launching next time), I right-click and select "Lock to Launcher".  But instead of an Evernote icon staying, a Wine icon stays that does nothing when I click on it.  I want to figure out how to get that Evernote icon to stay.

Answer (score 2):

You can start apps with wine through the comand `wine start /Unix "/absolute/path/to/file.exe"` or `wine start 'C:\absolute\path\to\file.exe'`. And you can create program links even in dash to find by creating a new `*.desktop` in the `/usr/share/applictions` folder.

So, do that and write into that file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Evernote
Icon=/path/to/icon
Type=Application
Exec=wine start '[PATH]'
```

If you can't find the icon, possibly it is packed into one of the *.exe files, search it (e.g. this http://findicons.com/files/icons/2653/android_icons_2/600/evernote.png), save it in PNG format (make sure you cut away white corners, this simply looks more right) and use it's location as icon path.

This should do it, displaying the icon and showing up in dash search so you should be able to keep it in the starter when you run it. Comment if somethings not working, maybe we have to wrap path or command into quotation marks.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and the new link shows up in the dash search.  But clicking on it does nothing (mouse pointer turns into a wheel for a couple seconds, no windows open).  Maybe spaces in the program path are a problem?  I should also mention that Evernote already showed up in dash (now there are two), and the original starts perfectly.  However, the problem is that the icon in the launcher is Wine, not Evernote.

Comment: Then, if it already exists, can you have a look at the value at `Exec=` there? Or maybe you just want to set its icon to your image, that's probably easier...

Comment: I didn't realize the .desktop file actually makes a desktop icon!  Lol.  It works and opens Evernote.  Plus, the icon that comes up in the launcher now looks like Evernote and launches it properly.  Thanks!  FYI, I'm not sure if a logout/login was required.  Also, quotation marks around the entry for [PATH] I think was required.

Comment: Wait, if I delete the desktop icon, the launcher icon also disappears.  So this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  Ideally, I'd like just the launcher icon.  Nothing else.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your comment, sorry (I'm german), The *.desktop file does _not_ contain the icon, it's referring to an image that gets displayed as icon. If you want to get the image out of the way I'd put it into the folder the *.exe is in, too.