# Desktop Shortcut to App

Tags: shortcuts

I have an app in /usr/local/AppDir/ called App.  I start this app from within the /usr/local/AppDir with the following command.

sudo ./App

How can I create a desktop shortcut that starts this app?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `*.desktop` file. Look into it's documentation or at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573010/how-can-i-get-a-program-i-run-in-wine-to-lock-to-my-launcher/573454#573454) answer.
For `Exec=` use your path `/usr/local/AppDir/App` and if you need sudo, do something like `gksudo /usr/local/AppDir/App`. `gksudo` asks for the sudo passphrase in a graphical Window.

Answer (score 0):

Make a text file on your desktop with name app.desktop or something_you_like.desktop and add following data to it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=sudo /usr/local/AppDir/App
Name=App
Comment=comment here
Icon=icon path here
```

Save the file and add make it executable by executing following command in terminal :

```
cd Desktop
chmod +x app.desktop
```

Comment: If it solves your problem ,  click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of the text, which means "I accept the answer"