# How the heck do I make jar files executable?

Tags: 12.04, xfce, chmod, executable, jar

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Chromebook 2 via crouton (I'm using the xfce4 desktop enviroment so don't give me Unity fixes) and I am trying to run a .jar program through OpenJDK6. I just can't get it to work. Everytime I try it tells me it's not executable. There is no checkbox to make it executable and chmod and sudo chmod aren't working. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in terminal, just type `java -jar /path/to/your/file.jar` and you're done.

If you want to start it the graphical way, you need a `*.desktop` file. Look into it's documentation or at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573010/how-can-i-get-a-program-i-run-in-wine-to-lock-to-my-launcher/573454#573454) answer.
For `Exec=` simply use the command above.